# Wave Background Flutter Assistance

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-custompainter

I have been struggling with this problem for the past 3ish days. Basically, I want the homepage of my app to have a wavelike pattern at the bottom of the screen. It is similar to this:
[image: Example]

However, I want my version of the wave to look like this:[image: My version]

How would I do this in flutter? I don't want to manually draw it and then use it as a jpg or png, I want to make it using containers or something native to flutter. Thanks!

Comment: you can use custom painter and draw it.

Comment: @MunsifAli Do you know how I would do that?

Comment: go to online shape maker for flutter create wave shape and copy the code from that use it in your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register and use this online tool to generate the curve.

https://fluttershapemaker.com

Watch this video to get an idea, how to use the tool

[shapemaker video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnKgtKxRLX4)

Finally generate the class from the tool and use it.

**Here is a sample code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint0 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1;

    Path path0 = Path();
    path0.moveTo(size.width * 0.0029500, size.height * 0.5714286);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.0394500, size.height * 0.5007143,
        size.width * 0.0999500, size.height * 0.5000000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.1583100, size.height * 0.5003571,
        size.width * 0.2039500, size.height * 0.5685714);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.2407000, size.height * 0.5006429,
        size.width * 0.2999800, size.height * 0.4993571);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.3602400, size.height * 0.5010714,
        size.width * 0.4003700, size.height * 0.5700000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.4403600, size.height * 0.5012714,
        size.width * 0.5000700, size.height * 0.5000000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.5604700, size.height * 0.5002286,
        size.width * 0.6011100, size.height * 0.5695857);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.6403500, size.height * 0.5004429,
        size.width * 0.7000400, size.height * 0.4998714);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.7604000, size.height * 0.4992857,
        size.width * 0.8011100, size.height * 0.5671429);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.8406100, size.height * 0.4996429,
        size.width * 0.9002000, size.height * 0.5000000);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.9602000, size.height * 0.4982143,
        size.width * 1.0029500, size.height * 0.5685714);
    path0.cubicTo(
        size.width * 0.7529500,
        size.height * 0.5692857,
        size.width * 0.7529500,
        size.height * 0.5692857,
        size.width * 0.0029500,
        size.height * 0.5714286);
    path0.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path0, paint0);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Add this to widget tree**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double curveWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      //
      CustomPaint(
        size: Size(
            curveWidth,
            (curveWidth * 0.7)
                .toDouble()), //You can Replace [curveWidth] with your desired width for Custom Paint and height will be calculated automatically
        painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
      ),
    ]));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! I managed to figure it out using chatgpt (to generate the curves). It took like 2 hours but chatgpt saved me so much. I will however mark your answer as accepted because if I didn't use ai to generate the code this answer would have helped a ton. Thanks! (PS: The video and online tool were SUPER helpful and I will be using them in the future)