# how can I make a shape like this in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I dont want to use package for navigation.I just want to create this shape.could you help me?

Comment: Does [How to make bottomNavigationBar notch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59455684/10157127) answer your question?

Comment: if that answers, I am thinking of  closing the question as duplicate also you can do it

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I made that but when I want give it padding from sides the appbar shape makes some mess.and the floating button doesnt fit at center.do you know how to do that?

Comment: It would be better to add minimal snippet on question that you've tried so far, so that others can help on specific issue. More about [asking goog question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this for any type of custom paint or shape in Flutter

[Wave Background Flutter Assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75915368/wave-background-flutter-assistance)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `BottomNavigationBar` widget with `BottomAppBar` Widget.

Add shape property in `BottomAppBar` widget

```
shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
```

Then change `FloatingActionButton` location to:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation : FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
```